# Where to buy rackmount kits for sonicwall and 3com switch

Tags: networking, mount, rack, hardware

Does somebody know where I can order some rackmount kits that fit with a sonicwall nsa 3500 firewall, 3com 3300mx switch and 3com 4200 switch.
They got lost when we moved to a new office

Comment: What country are you in? I know a place up the road here, but it won't be much help unless you are in New Zealand too.

Answer (score 2):

Again, searching for "Rack mount shelves" will probably be your best bet if the vendor doesn't sell a rack mount kit.